# apply() to columns of data.frame

Tags: r

I don't quite understand the behavior of `apply()` in case of data.frame columns:

```
apply(mtcars, 2, is.numeric)
# mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 

apply(iris,   2, is.numeric)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
# FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE
```

in both tables we have numeric data, so why the result is different?
Moreover, if I add a column to `mtcars`, it changes the outcome for all columns:

```
mtcars$colA <- 'charA'
apply(mtcars, 2, is.numeric)
# mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  colA 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

For my purpose (determine the type of columns), `lapply` does the job (`lapply(mtcars, is.numeric)`) - but I still would like to figure out what's going on in case of `apply(df,2,myfunc)`

Comment: Hmm...`apply` coerces to matrix before doing any calculations. Since matrices can not hold more than one classes then this is what you are seeing. Either they are all numeric or not. This also explains why none are numeric in `mtcars` once you add a character variable. If you try it with `sapply` then you will get the real classes of the original df. Try `sapply(iris, is.numeric)`

Comment: ouch, how could I miss that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could paste it as an answer?

Comment: be sure to check this FAQ for some good intuition to take away: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/3576984

Comment: @MichaelChirico, just realized I even had that question bookmarked already! shame  on me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of `apply`,

> Details
>
> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

Since these objects are only able to hold one single class, then you will either get that all are numeric or If there is at least one non-numeric column, then you will get `FALSE` for all. We can compare it with the results of `sapply`,

```
apply(iris, 2, is.numeric)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#       FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE 

sapply(iris, is.numeric)
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE
```